# How to fetch the appID without using Branch SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, branch

I am working in iOS swift project. I have integrated branch for deep link activity. In the branch link we have appended the appID and retrieved the id when the user clicked the app link using below code in didFinishLaunch in AppDelegate.

```
      let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
        branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController: true, deepLinkHandler: { params, error in
         if error == nil {
                   // parse appID
          }
        })
```

But sometimes, we can’t fetch the ID due to branch error. So we planned to remove branch integration in our code. But plist contains URL Scheme, URL identifier etc.. for navigate to this app.

So, When the user clicks the app link, how to fetch the value with out using above code?

**Additional note:**
The below function is not triggered in my app while clicking the app link. Is any other way to trigger this function, so that I can check the url value in the below function to processing further.

```
   func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
}
```

Comment: The app ID is `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier` or `Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleIdentifier")` .

Comment: No, the appID is something like unique 9 digit value from the API. EG: Q23ihfkKh